# Look up X in table Prolog

Tags: prolog

How do I get my Prolog code to return something in the database instead of just answering `yes` and `no`?

I have this small table

```
student('Pelt', '67890').
grade('PH100', '67890', 'C plus').
```

How do I write a lookup function that returns `'C plus'` when I pass in `'Pelt'`? This is what I have but I don't think it's going anywhere.

```
lookupGrade(X) :- student(X, Y), grade(W, Y, Z).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prolog rules don't return values as C functions.

In you want extract the grade of a student you should pass two elements to your `lookupGrade`; but (suggestion from Mat; thanks) I change the name in `student_grade` (the reason is explained at the end).

The rule could be something like

```
student_grade(Name, Grade) :- student(Name, Code), grade(_, Code, Grade).
```

Using it as

```
 student_grade('Pelt', G)
```

you "unify" in `G` the value `'C plus'`.

Note that this rule works also in the opposite direction; with

```
 student_grade(N, 'C plus')
```

you unify `'Pelt'` in `N`.

And this is the reason why `lookupGrade` is a bad name: can be a "lookup grade" if you pass an atom as name and a variable for grade; can be a "lookup student" if you pass an atom as grade and a variable for name; can be (toghether with `findall/3`, by example) used to find all matches student/grade if you pass to it two variables.

Comment: Please expand on the name:  `lookupGrade` does not make sense if the grade is already instantiated, is in queries like: `lookupGrade('Pelt', 'C plus')` and `lookupGrade_, 'A')`. I suggest `student_grade/2`. It makes sense in all directions.

Comment: @mat - you're right; thanks; modified my answer. Take in count that I have big troubles with English (and that I'm a rookie with Prolog) so have no qualms if you want to edit end correct my answers.

Comment: Great edit, +1! I'd rather not edit such answers but first discuss a bit with the author so that we both benefit.